# HttpClient Get returns 200 but Post returns 404

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache http client to make a Get and a Post call to the same endpoint.  The Get returns 200 OK, but the Post returns 404 Not Found.  Any ideas?  My setup is as follows:

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
 String key = "foo"

 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://url");
 HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(httpGet);
 System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
 HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
 EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
 // Returns 200 OK

 String bundle = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://url");
 StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(
     bundle,
     "application/json",
     "UTF-8");
 httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
 HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(httpPost);
 System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
 HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
 EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
 // Returns 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Are you able to make the post using a tool such as Postman?

Comment: Yes, I can make the post using Postman.

Comment: Have you done a side-by-side comparison of the payload sent by Postman vs. the one sent by your code to see what the diffs are and if you can spot anything obvious?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the request body, I get 404 even if I set the body to "{}".

Comment: The whole HTTP request - the request line, the headers and the body.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the same URL of your server accepts both `POST` and `GET` ,  it maybe because the server endpoint treats `POST` and `GET` as different routes and accepts only `GET`, returning `404` to your `POST` request.
So it is not a problem of your http client, but rather the server.